# Bootstrap make column fit

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap page where I am experiencing one minor issue. The issue is in desktop mode, one column does not reach the area where it needs to. If I modify the height in the css it pushes the other two divs downward. How do i make the Top div reach the bottom area where the tools section end without pushing corner and tools div down? Is this possible with bootstrap?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body style="background:#F8F8F8;">
    <p>
        <br/>
    </p>

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <a href="" class="navbar-brand">
                    <img alt="" src="image.png" height="22" width="81" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">


                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <BR>
        <BR>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4" "col-xs-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="welcome">
                            <div id="container">
      Test info

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" "col-xs-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="prescription">
                            <div id="container">
                                PL
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" "col-xs-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="profile">
                            <div id="container">
                               Profile
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="ghabox">
                            <div id="container2">
                                Ask
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="ghabox">
                            <div id="container2">
                                Discussions
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" "col-xs-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="contributors">
                            <div id="container2">
                                Top 
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="ghabox">
                            <div id="container2">
                              Corner
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="ghabox">
                            <div id="container2">
                                Tools
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>






        </div>



    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Comment: Please view the desktop view of this. I want just the "top" div height to expand to reach the same area that the other two end at. If i adjust the css height for this div, it pushes the other 2 divs down. How can i accomplish this without pushing them down. Someone please provide a sample that works on desktop view.

Comment: @dippas your answer helped--thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the site the grid nesting site on bootstrap, I have a solutions.

```
`<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-9"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6" style="height:100px;backgroundcolor:lightblue;"></div><div class="col-sm-6" style="height:100px;background-color:white;"></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12" style="height:150px;background-color:red;"></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-4" style="height:150px;background-color:orange;"</div><div class="col-sm-4" style="height:150px;background-color:yellow;"</div><div class="col-sm-4" style="height:150px;background-color:green;"></div></div></div><div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:black;height:400px;"></div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, the corner and tools div should be inside the Top div for the Top div to wrap around them.

```
 <div class="col-md-6" "col-xs-4">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="contributors">
          <div id="container2">
            Top 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="ghabox">
                <div id="container2">
                  Corner
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="ghabox">
                <div id="container2">
                  Tools
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

See this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qbyCrvfuplxxdAdSeq3G?p=preview)